# If all/one parameter is/are null?

Tags: sql

```
create Procedure Proc_selectEmp
(
@name varchar(10) = null,
@lname varchar(10) = null,
@id varchar(10) = null

)
as
begin

select * from Emp
where 
(@name is null or name = @name) 
and (@lname is null or lname = @lname) 
and (@id is null or id = @id)
end
```

My basic query: `select *  from Emp`. If user enter name, it will get added and query will be:

```
select *  
from Emp 
where name = txtname.Text
```

Here is my sp. It handle properly.

Is there any other option by using `isnull()` and `case`.

Comment: Required reading on this topic http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
where   ISNULL(@name,name) = name  
and     ISNULL(@lname,lname) = lname
and     ISNULL(@id,id) = id
```